# PHP mysqli_query not freeing memory on mysqli_free_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a long script which is supposed to run many queries one after the other. The problem is as long as the script doesn't end, memory usage never decreases even on unset or mysqli_free_result.

I've attached some sample code which gives an issue. The table TMP_DUMP contains 500K rows.

```
    public function memTest() {

        echo "start";

        $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","####","####");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $products = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM TMP_DUMP");

        mysqli_free_result($products);
        mysqli_close($con);

        echo "done";
        sleep(500);
    }
```

So I keep htop open and see the RAM usage after start print. The memory keeps increasing and stabilizes after a point but it should decrease when done is printed but it doesn't. If I wait for the script to end, the memory then suddenly decreases by the same amount it increased.

Comment: How did you check the memory usage ? by an OS utility ? or with PHP's `memory_get_usage` ?

Comment: Consider using unbuffered queries in case there are many rows to return.

Comment: @Accountantم  used htop. But the problem is even if the os utility isn't accurate, my script gets killed if I run multiple such queries by the OS as RAM usage keeps increasing and doesn't free up

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you see the code I haven't fetched any data. So it doesn't matter if I use unbuffered query after this as I will still to query first.

Comment: @AkashPopat did you try to test with `memory_get_usage` before and after `mysqli_free_result` ?

Comment: @AkashPopat it, actually, does

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think this is different from dupe unset question as `mysqli_free_result` should free the memory used by the PHP process, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Accountantم well if you think it's another dupe you can suggest the link in the comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No I mean this question is not a duplicate for the unset question, because `mysqli_free_result` should actually free the memory used by the PHP process.

Comment: @Accountantم surely you can provide a source for such a notion?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm sorry you are right, **"All associated result memory is automatically freed at the end of the script's execution."** [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php#refsect1-function.mysql-free-result-description)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes you are right, adding MYSQLI_USE_RESULT in the query did this trick. Can you add this as an answer and remove this question as a duplicate so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I also tested and yes you are right, after using `free_result()` using `memory_get_usage(true)` shows that PHP still consuming 400MB and `memory_get_usage()` shows 2MB.